# ActionController::UnknownFormat when using respond_to do |format|

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using jquery slider ui and rails 4. I am trying to implement a price slider for my product page. However, i have run into a problem. I have tried to search around but i cant seems to find a solution that helps. Hope someone could help me as I am quite new to ruby on rails. Thanks.

Here are my code

products_controller.rb

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'x_product_list', :partial => 'products/products_list', :locals => { :product => @product }
```

with this error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: How does your request log look?

Comment: And you have a `views/products/update.js.erb` file, right?

Comment: Show us the request you made (with the url): make sure you append `.js` at the end.

Comment: @Vimsha how do i get the request log?

Comment: @PinnyM no, i do not have that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating adding JS to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`, so rails knows how to deal with it.

```ruby
Mime::Type.register "application/javascript", :js
```

Be sure to restart your app after editing that file.